# How to install java in container while writing it in Dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker, scheduler

I am naive in software development. I want to run a jar file from [Dkron](http://dkron.io/) Scheduler using cron job. I am running dkron in docker(using docker-compose up). I am passing "command": "java --version" to see if I can run java from Dkron. As docker do not have java installed I changed the dockerfile.hub file to this:

```
FROM alpine
LABEL maintainer="Victor Castell <victor@victorcastell.com>"

RUN set -x \
    && buildDeps='bash ca-certificates openssl tzdata' \ 
    && apk add --update $buildDeps \
    && apk add openjava8                                #add this line to install java
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /opt/local/dkron

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk             #add this line to install java
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin                           #add this line to install java

EXPOSE 8080 8946

ENV SHELL /bin/bash
WORKDIR /opt/local/dkron

COPY dkron .
COPY dkron-* ./
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/local/dkron/dkron"]

CMD ["--help"]
```

When I again do docker-compose up it do not give any error, still on passing "command": "java --version" by json through UI, dkron shows error - exec : "java" : executable file not found in $PATH.

What can I do to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Docker are you running? It may also help your question get noticed if you paste your Dockerfile into the answer rather than linking to it, as that makes it easier for people to read the whole thing in one place.

Comment: I am using docker version 2.3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create JVM in docker container using dkron as the base image, (publically available) and build another image on top of it.

Here is dockerfile I created for running java application

```
FROM dkron/dkron
WORKDIR /root/hello-world
COPY hello.java /root/hello-world

RUN apk add openjdk8

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

RUN javac hello.java
```

Then I build image. Let id be xxx
Then I ran the image and build dkron server as
docker run  -p 8080:8080 xxx agent --server --bootstrap-expect=1 --node-name=node1

Answer (score 0):

Try this file

```
FROM alpine
LABEL maintainer="Victor Castell <victor@victorcastell.com>"

RUN set -x \
        && buildDeps='bash ca-certificates openssl tzdata' \
        && apk add --update $buildDeps \
        && apk add openjdk8 \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
        && mkdir -p /opt/local/dkron

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

EXPOSE 8080 8946

ENV SHELL /bin/bash
WORKDIR /opt/local/dkron

COPY dkron .
COPY dkron-* ./
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/local/dkron/dkron"]

CMD ["--help"]
```

alpine package doesn't have `openjava8` packages.

Edit: Update ENV variables

Comment: Still doesn't work. Changed it openjdk and removed both ENV. I am using MacOS(just for info)

Comment: Does the problem change?

Comment: No, still getting exec: "java": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: I have updated `ENV` variables section, please check

Comment: Adding ENV variable I am unable to create any job. Error message - dkron_1         | time="2020-09-19T08:06:23Z" level=info msg="2020-09-19T08:06:23.973Z [ERROR] raft: failed to make requestVote RPC: target=\"{Voter ede47012eb05 172.18.0.2:6868}\" error=\"codec.decoder: readContainerLen: Unrecognized descriptor byte: hex: 0, dec: 0\""

Comment: Brother, you may have wrong dockerfile or the steps are not completely written,  your error about the JAVA is resolved I guess, please confirm by running `java --version` command.

Comment: I am making edit in Dkron dockerhub. Available at https://hub.docker.com/r/dkron/dkron/dockerfile. I am not able to create job after making edits as you said

Comment: Since you have made changes in the mentioned `dockerfile`, I am not sure what should I suggest, you question was about java error in your container, so I tried to answer. I am not familiar with `Dkron` so can't help you there and also github repository related to docker image is already archived, I am not sure if the image has issues or the product, so you must create another question about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221729/discussion-between-code-mechanic-and-paul-jay).