# Need clarification on command in Dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker, scheduler

I am trying to run jar file through open source Dkron scheduler. I am need to modify docker file to install java in container. Please clarify me what copy command means here

```
FROM golang:1.14
LABEL maintainer="Victor Castell <victor@victorcastell.com>"

EXPOSE 8080 8946

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV GO111MODULE=on
COPY go.mod go.mod
COPY go.sum go.sum            #here
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN go install ./...

CMD ["dkron"]
```

It also has dockerfile.hub which contains this

```
FROM alpine
MAINTAINER Victor Castell <victor@victorcastell.com>

ENV DKRON_VERSION 0.11.0

RUN set -x \
    && buildDeps='bash ca-certificates openssl' \
    && apk add --update $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /opt/local/dkron \
    && wget -O /opt/local/dkron/dkron.tar.gz https://github.com/victorcoder/dkron/releases/download/v${DKRON_VERSION}/dkron_${DKRON_VERSION}_linux_amd64.tar.gz \
    && cd /opt/local/dkron \
    && tar -xzf dkron.tar.gz \
    && rm /opt/local/dkron/dkron.tar.gz

EXPOSE 8080 8946

ENV SHELL /bin/bash
WORKDIR /opt/local/dkron

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/local/dkron/dkron"]

CMD ["--help"]
```

Also what changes need to be done to make java file run in the container? Thank you.

Comment: What does the documentation say about the `COPY` command?

Comment: I can't find it in documentation. I get it COPY source destination, but why it mentions here, When source and destination is same

Comment: When <src> and <dest> are the same, you're still talking about two different locations, <src> being relative to the Dockerfile, and <dest> being inside the container you're constructing?

Comment: Regarding your second question...I'd suggest that you Google `running a java program in a docker container`.  There are many tutorials.  You'll have to combine one of them with the `dkron` Dockerfile, or find an existing place where that work has already been done.  Explaining to you how to do that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965436/how-to-install-java-in-container-while-writing-it-in-dockerfile   I did. I explained more to it here.

Answer (score 1):

> The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from <src> and adds them to the filesystem **of the container** at the path <dest>.

this is from the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Answer (score 0):

> Please clarify me what copy command means here
> ...
>
> ```
> COPY . .
> ```

The copy step takes files from the build context and copies them into a layer of the resulting image. The build context is passed from the client to the docker engine as the one arg in the build command, typically a `.` to indicate the current directory is sent as the build context.

You can change the source to be another stage during a multi-stage build, allowing you to transfer build artifacts from a compiler environment to a runtime environment you wish to deploy. And you can change it to pull files from another image. Both of these are done with the `--from` option to the copy step.

Note that this command only works one way, the destination is always the image you are building, and since the source was historically always the build context, the scope on the source and destination are not included in the syntax. E.g. docker shortened `COPY build-context:. container:.` to just `COPY . .`.

Important links in the documention:

- copy step: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy
- build context: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage